# Order 2 different querysets by date

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

This is a simple question, I could achieve this with a for loop and lots of comparisons, but I am wondering if there is a better way.

I have two querysets:

```
  comments = Comment.objects.all()
  actions = Action.objects.all()
```

So, I need a list with both comments and actions ordered by date. The `Comment` model and the `Action` model have a date (`date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`) field.

In other words:

```
wall = [] # Alternate Comments and Actions ordered by date
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have list of combined comments and actions

```
comments = Comment.objects.all()
actions = Action.objects.all()
from itertools import chain
wall = list(chain(comments, actions))
```

You can sort then the python list of objects by attribute, which is date in your case

```
wall.sort(key=lambda x: x.date)
```

You can also pass reverse True/False in lambda function, for descending and ascending order

```
wall.sort(key=lambda X:x.date, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is something that the Django ORM is great at!

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters

```
comments = Comment.objects.order_by('date')
actions = Actions.objects.order_by('date')
```

Then you can loop through both lists, and because they are already ordered by date you only need a single pairwise comparison for each element to sort them by date!